# What is encapsulation? How does it actually hide data?

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns, encapsulation, hidden-field

Searching turns up a simple definition: data hiding.

But, consider the following two examples:

**1) First Example:**

```
Class Employee
{
    public int age;
}
```

**2) Second Example:**

```
Class Employee
{
    private int age;

    public int getAge(){return age;}
}
```

**Question:**
In both the above specified examples, there is no data hiding, as `age` is either being modified by others or being viewed by others. Where is the data hiding? How does encapsulation help in the above examples?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: @Reno, Encapsulation doesn't means to just to protect data from modification. What if I added one more setter method.... based on your explanation, it means that encapsulation means read only properties of class ...which is not....i sure....

Comment: Also see: [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) by Jon Skeet

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There *is* data hiding. The second example hides *how* the value is stored. Also, the second example makes the value read-only for code outside the class. By having private fields and exposing them through methods or properties you immediately gain some advantages, some of which are:

- Access control granularity; you can choose to make the value publicly read-only, read-write or write-only.
- Possibility to validate input prior to storing the value
- Possibility to add logging or other auditing mechanisms

Note that encapsulation is not only about having access control. The primary use for encapsulation is to *hide implementation details from calling code*. When calling code wants to retrieve a value, it should not depend on *from where* the value comes. Internally, the class can store the value in a field or retrieve it from some external resource (such as a file or a database). *Perhaps the value is not stored at all*, but calculated on-the-fly. This should not matter to the calling code.

When you expose the value through a method or property, you shield calling code from such details, which also gives you the possibility to change the implementation, without affecting calling code.

Comment: So does it means that adding a setter method to the property will break encapsulation?

Comment: @anil: no, not at all. Encapsulation is about hiding implementation details. By having the field private and exposing it through methods, you encapsulate the internal implementation details. The value could be stored in a field, in a file on disk, in a database, it could be calculated on-the-fly, whatever. The calling code does (and should) not know such details. That is encapsulation.

Comment: I guess hiding implementation details relates to abstraction not encapsulation. Now that sounds two different names are being used for the same term. look at this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @anil: I would say that encapsulation is a form of abstraction. This is also supported by the text you linked to: *The term encapsulation refers to the hiding of state details* (in the paragraph [Abstraction in object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Abstraction_in_object_oriented_programming))

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation separates the concept of *what something does* from *how it is implemented*.

Encapsulation is a very important concept in Object Oriented Programming. It is hiding the data from other modules in the application. In your example 2, as you can see you can only get the age and that too using a getter method, but you can only set the value to the private member within that class and not outside it. This is the advantage of Encapsulation.

Comment: how did polymorphism join this party?

Comment: @GregC, oops! I meant it to be Encapsulation. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Think about this variant:

```
class Employee
{
    private int _age;

    public string Age
    {
        get { return _age.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

In your example the outside and inside use an integer and that is confusing. (Similar to showing 2 * 2 = 4 to explain multiplication and forgetting that 2 + 2 = 4 too)

Comment: @UGEEN, Erno, using same datatype inside and outside doesn't creates any confusion. That sound strange that you are converting it into string for many reason client may need it as integer. So is there any genuine reason to convert it to string..moreover how it helps encapsulation?

Comment: The transformation to string is just to show that on the outside the type can be very different from the inside. Of course, when a client needs it as an integer the Age property should be of that type. The example is just to show that the property-get encapsulates (or can encapsulate) the inner dataformat.

Answer (score 1):

`Encapsulation` is `data hiding` simply.

let's see how encapsulation happens.
Assume you create a Employee class and include two instance variables. name and salary. You don't make them private. Now what happens another class in the program can access these two variables simply by creating an object if the employee class. So what we want is to hide these both or salary information to outside classes.

If we want to hide salary We can simply declare salary as a `private` variable. Now we know even another class create an object and try to access salary as before it doesn't work. Because it is a private field which is only accessible to Employee class. Now we have hidden our data.

But assume that we need a person to enter salary details of each of the employees. 
I will make it more clear.
The data entering person has 3 types of data to enter `woked_hours, OT and leaves` (Emplyee class has three variables for this). 
We want this person to enter these details but we `do not want` him to `see` how the `salary calculation` is done. It is done according to the mathematical equation which is inside Employee class.

So he cannot calculate and enter salary it self. But we let him  see the final salary. there We create a method to get the value of the salary inside employee class. it is

```
public int getSalary()
{
   return salary;
}
```

He knows this, that there are two methods he can use to access those hidden fields. `set method and get method.` So he `call getmethod.` yes he `can see` the `salary` information. Because we have created the getMethod to return salary. Now he try to use set method to enter a new salary amount to change current value of salary. so he call `e.setSalary(1000);` But it gives an error. Why? because in the employee class there is no method written as

```
   public void setSalary(int newSalary)
   {
   salary=newSalary;
   }
```

We intentionally didn't write that code because we don't want him to set salary value straight away. So we have hidden some information but some we still let him access. We gave him access to `Read only`. But `not Write` for salary.

so wasn't it useful now that encapsulation we have done.

The same way as he is allowed to `set` these fields `woked_hours, OT and leaves` . for those fields we have given him access to Write only. There we intentionally do not write `getter methods`. If you write both `getter` and setter you are allowing him to `READ/ Write` both access.

It doesn't matter only set or get, The field is private, the field is hidden already data is hidden. But some access is given through `getters` and `setters` .

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the variable age is set as a public variable. Here anyone can modify the meeber age when an object of type Employee is declared.

However, in your second example the variable age is actually private, and can only be modified from inside of the class Employee. This is the case of data hiding.

In object oriented programming encapsulation is when one object is composed of another. This is in contrast to inheritance where an object can extent an already existing class.

Comment: As I had already commented in others response's, that is that you mean only one setter will break encapsulation. Do you mean that read-only properties can achieve encapsulation. I am sure it is not. As every one responded based on second method but what if a simple setter method is added?

Answer (score 0):

There is more to Encapsulation than data hiding. Encapsulation allows you to keep **all** the data and the functionality pertinent to an entity with this entity. Levels of visibility of this data is a related, but not identical, concept. E.g. an `Employee` object caries all employee data and functionality (methods) with it. Note that this is not **enforced**, but **enabled** by the OO languages.

This may sound natural to you if you were born into the OO era, but this was **the** big leap from Functional Programming to OOP, both conceptual (design) and in languages that support this paradigm.

Quoting from Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29):

> In a programming language
>   encapsulation is used to refer to one
>   of two related but distinct notions,
>   and sometimes to the combination
>   thereof:
>
> - A language mechanism for restricting    access to some of the
>     object's    components.
> - A language construct that    facilitates the bundling of data with 
>     the methods (or other functions)
>     operating on that data.

Answer (score 0):

Say I use your code like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
int age = employee.getAge();
// Do something with age
```

Here, unless I look at your source code, I have absolutely no idea how `Employee` has calculated its age. For all I know, `getAge()` could look like this:

```
public int getAge() {
    return new java.util.Random().nextInt( 100 );
}
```

or perhaps something even more complicated. I just don't know.

So in your second example, the fact that `getAge()` just returns a private member variable is completely hidden from me.